# Storing error providers in dynamic variables

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, errorprovider

**OverView**

I am working on this project which has 12 `error providers` all of which have their own unique name, and purpose. I know I can use one however I need to ensure that they all have their own error message for the user. 
The project is `winform` and i want all of the validation to be evaluated on my save button, which subscribes to a  `click event`.

**My issue**

I need to be able to asses whether any `error providers` are active before continuing with the save function. I have this following code which works however it is rather cumbersome and long-winded. I also need to display the error messages to the user, so they can indicate which field s are invalid.

**Validation Method**

```
bool IsValidIn()
            {
                foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
                {
                    if (c is SpellBox)
                    {
                        //SpellBox txt = (SpellBox)c;
                        if (epForeName.GetError(c).Length > 0 || epSurname.GetError(c).Length > 0 
                                                              || epPostcode.GetError(c).Length > 0
                                                              || epCountry.GetError(c).Length > 0
                                                              || epCounty.GetError(c).Length > 0
                                                              || epHouseName.GetError(c).Length > 0
                                                              || epLocality.GetError(c).Length > 0
                                                              || epStreetName.GetError(c).Length > 0
                                                              || epMobile.GetError(c).Length > 0
                                                              || epLandline.GetError(c).Length > 0
                                                              || epAlternative.GetError(c).Length > 0
                                                              || epEmail.GetError(c).Length > 0)
                        { return false; }
                    }
                }
                return true;}
```

**Save Click event**

```
 public void btn_SaveDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                //txt_ForeName_Validated(this, e);


                if (IsValidIn())
                {

                    _IsValid = true;
                    BtnPressed = "Ok";
                    HouseName = txt_HouseName.Text;
                    HouseNumber = Convert.ToString(nud_HouseNumber.Value);
                    StreetName = txt_StreetName.Text;
                    Locality = txt_Locality.Text;
                    Town = txt_Town.Text;
                    County = txt_County.Text;
                    Country = txt_Country.Text;
                    PostCode = txt_Postcode.Text;
                    Email = txt_Email.Text;
                    Title = cmb_Title.Text;
                    BirthDate = Convert.ToString(dateTimePicker1.Text);
                    ForeName = txt_ForeName.Text;
                    SurName = txt_SurName.Text;
                    PrefContNum = cmb_PrefConNumber.Text;
                    PrefContTime = cmb_PrefConTime.Text;
                    Mobile = txt_Mobile.Text;
                    Landline = txt_LndLine.Text;
                    Alternative = txt_Alt.Text;

                    this.Close();

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Errors present in form, please review!!!"); //MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes);
                }
            }
```

**Possible solution.**

I was thinking of possibly storing the variables into a collection of some-sort, more than likely a dictionary, by storing my variables into a dynamic variable, then iterate through the `Error-providers` themselves  however I am really unsure of the possibility of whether it will even be possible. If there is a simple way of refactoring this function I would be very appreciated if someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use dynamics here. You can simply store your `ErrorProvider` objects in a `List<ErrorProvider>`. Use `errorProviders.Any(e => e.GetError(c).Length > 0)` to determine if any error exists.

Comment: Cheers Could u give me an example as Im getting an error with your 'Any'. I created it like   `List<ErrorProvider> errorProviders = new List<ErrorProvider>()` Ive Populated my List as follows `errorProviders.Add(epSurname)` However I cant get it to work Would you be able to provide a example of how you mean ?

Comment: @whatdoyouNeedFromMe -- you need to ensure that all your various ErrorProvider derived from the same ErrorProvider class (ie: epForeName, epSurname, epPostcode, etc). An example of declaration in the above could be `var errorProviders = new List<ErrorProvider>() {epForeName, epSurname, epPostcode, ... };` then when you are trying to check individually if there was any error -- instead of `if (epForeName.GetError(c).Length  > 0 || ... ` you could use `errorProviders.Any(e => e.GetError(c).Length > 0` to replace the multiple lines.

Comment: @whatdoyouNeedFromMe I thought you haven't populated the list before. What error did you get?

Comment: I had an error on the `Any` keyword. And they are all different instances of  the` error provider ` class, so they do not all spawn from the same instance.

Comment: Saying does not contain a definition for ''Any accepting a first argument

Comment: My mistake just realised didn't have the LINQ Assembly sorry for the stupid comment

Answer (score 0):

I think this will give what you want

```
bool IsValidIn()
            {
                foreach (Control c in panel1.Controls)
                {
                    if (c is SpellBox)
                    {
                        //SpellBox txt = (SpellBox)c;
                        string errorStr = string.Empty;
                        if (epForeName.GetError(c).Length > 0)
                            errorStr = "epForeName";
                        else if(epSurname.GetError(c).Length > 0)
                            errorStr = "epSurname";
                        .
                        .
                        .
                        else if(epEmail.GetError(c).Length > 0)
                            errorStr = "epEmail";


                        if(errorStr != String.Empty) 
                            return false; 

                    }
                }
                return true;}
```

// just return the errorStr for getting error.

Comment: Thank you however  I am getting a syntax error on 'error = epEmail'   cannot convert type Of error provider to string.

Comment: Sorry but your answer only checks email, forename and surname. If i was to implement this for evry error prov it would be even longer than what i have currently